# printmat function: Decimal and percentage

Tags: matlab, matrix, format, output

I am very new to MATLAB. I am sorry if my question is basic. I am using "printmat" function to show some matrices in the command console. For example, printmat(A) and printmat(B), where A = 2.79 and B = 0.45e-7 is a scalar (for the sake of simplicity).

How do I increase the precision arbitrarily to seven decimals? For example: my output looks like 2.7943234 and B = 0.00000004563432.

How do I add a currency (say dollar) figure to the output of printmat?

How do I add a percentage figure (%) to the output of printmat?

Note: The reason I use printmat is that I can name my rows and columns. If you know a better function that can do all above, I would be glad to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards Mariam. From what I understand, you would like to display the numbers and show their full precision. I am also newbie, If I may contribute, you could convert the number data to string data (for display purposes) by using the `sprintf` function.

I am using the variable `A=2.7943234` as example. This value will not display the full precision, instead it will display `2.7943`. To show all the decimal tails, you could first convert this to string by

```
a = sprintf('%0.8f',A);
```

It will set the value `a` to a string `'2.79432340'`. The `%0.8f` means you want it to display 8 decimal tails. For this example,`%0.7f` is sufficient of course.

Another example: `A=0.00000004563432`, use `%0.14f`.

```
A=0.00000004563432; 
a=sprintf('%0.14f $ or %%',A);
```

the output should be : `'0.00000004563432 $ or %'`.

You could analyze further in https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html

You could try this first. If this does not help to reach your objective, I appreciate some inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. What happens if A is a vector or matrix? I tried sprintf on matrix and vector, but it return output as a string, but vector or matrix. I would appreciate if you put some light on this issue.

Comment: @Mariam . You could implement `sprintf` and store the value at each loop, while creating a new *cell* of the corresponding strings. The number of loops would be equal to the number of your matrix elements. (**this is one way, I have not found the shortcut to store *cell* of strings using `sprintf`.

Comment: @MariamSalehi , a *cell array* can contain any types of data. To initiate a variable of *cell array*, use `B={};` for example. Access or edit each element by `B{index}` . You also could read and practice from these Matlab documentations 
- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html?searchHighlight=cell&s_tid=doc_srchtitle
 and
 - https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html?searchHighlight=cell&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

To learn about `for` loop :

 -  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html?searchHighlight=for&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `printmat` function is *very* [obsolete](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/143944) now. I think [`table` objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) are its intended successor (and functions such as [`array2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) to convert a matrix to a table of data). Tables allow you to add row and column names and format the columns in different ways. I don't think there's a way to add `$` or `%` to each number, but you *can* [specify the units of each column](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table-properties.html#property_d0e987225).

In general, you can also format the display precision using [`format`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html). Something like this may be what you want:

```
format long
```